# Unable to Set Response Headers in Abstract or Extended Class

Tags: apex, apexrest

I am trying to set the Content-type header to application/json on REST response in apex and no matter where I set it, it always returns application/octetstream. I am using an abstract base class. When I remove the references to the base class the headers take fine. I have tried moving the addHeader call to the child class as well. Even when setting at the end of code execution, debug shows application/json as the only header value, method exits immediately following. But response still shows Content-type: application/octetstream. This is also true when I just send blob.valueOf('testString') as the responseBody. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
public abstract class RESTHandler {
  public static RESTHandler newInstance() {
    return (RESTHandler) Application.Service.newInstance(RESTHandler.class);
  }

  public RESTHandler() {
  }

  public void run() {
    RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    try {
      this.handleRequest(
        RestContext.request,
        RestContext.response,
        RestContext.request.requestBody?.toString()
      );
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      this.respond(ex);
    } finally {
      RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    }
  }

  /*
   * Overridable handler
   */
  public abstract void handleRequest(
    RESTRequest req,
    RESTResponse res,
    String body
  );

  public void respond(CustomRESTResponseClass r, Integer statusCode) {
    RestContext.response.statusCode = statusCode;
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(r.toJSON());
  }
}


@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/my-endpoint/*')
global with sharing class ChildRESTHandler extends RESTHandler {
  global static ChildRESTHandler newInstance() {
    return (ChildRESTHandler) Application.Service.newInstance(
      ChildRESTHandler.class
    );
  }

  @HttpPost
  global static void doPost() {
    ChildRESTHandler handler = ChildRESTHandler.newInstance();
    handler.run();
  }

  global override void handleRequest(
    RESTRequest req,
    RESTResponse res,
    String body
  ) {
    ChildRESTRequest requestBody = (ChildRESTRequest) JSON.deserialize(
      body,
      ChildRESTRequest.class
    );

    try {
      this.respond(new ChildRESTResponse(), 201);
    } catch (CustomException e) {
      // exception response
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like the abstract class and all its methods need to be Global in order for the header to take